# Finding domain where this complex logarithm identity holds

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I have not had much exposure to more advanced complex analysis exercises, although this one might be easy, and the solution just completely escapes me. I am determining the set of complex numbers for which the identity

\begin{equation}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right) = a(1-z)-b(z)-i\pi \end{equation}
holds, where

\begin{align*}
\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right), &\quad \quad \arg\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right) \in [-\pi, \pi) \\
a(1-z) = \log\left(1-z\right), &\quad \quad \arg\left(1-z\right) \in [0, 2\pi)\\
b(z) = \log(z), &\quad \quad \arg(z) \in [-\pi, \pi).
\end{align*}

I was tempted to observe simply the complex parts of $\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)$ such that we have

\begin{align*}
\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right) &= \ln\left|\frac{z-1}{z}\right|+i\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right) \\
&= \ln|1-z| - \ln|z| + i\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)
\end{align*}
and compare the arguments of each side, though I'm not sure how to proceed from here. My other question, albeit off-topic, is if the power series for the left side in the first equation would hold true for the right side (in this case, we would have a Laurent series). That is, does it make sense that we would have
$$ a(1-z)-b(z)-i\pi = -\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{nz^n}$$
or this some absurdity? I am missing some fundamentals here. Your support is very much appreciated!